# How to manage Socket.IO listeners outside activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, socket.io

I have an application working with multiple Activities on Android.
The connection to the server is managed by Socket.IO channels.

For the moment I'm initialising the socket.on events in a common class.

However as this "socket" class is initialized at the app launch and so outside of the different activities, I'm not able to manipulate my views directly from there.

I would like to avoid writing my listeners in the activities as some receivers are common to them (for example the authentication part, valid throughout the whole app).

Here is the scheme :

- Socket.class -> Has methods to init the Socket.IO "on" listeners.
- Activity 1 : Launches the Socket.IO connection and registers the listeners.
- Activity 2 : Should be manipulated by the socket class.

I don't know if i'm clear, don't hesitate to ask me further details.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Why don't have a base activity class that implements the common methods and listeners for the events?

Comment: I have my MainActivity class. Will it have access then to the Activities related views and layouts ?

Comment: I was actually thinking of a Abstract activity with some implemented methods and some abstract methods that you would extends in your others activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1 - Make an interface:

```
public interface OnSocketListener {
    void method(); //add some methods to comunicate between your class and your activities
}
```

2 - Have your listener called from your class:

```
public class SocketClass {
    private OnSockectListener mListener;
    public void setListener(OnSockectListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

   private void someEvent() {
       if (mListener != nul) {
           mListener.onSomeEvent(Data data);
       }
   }
}
```

3 - Have a base activity implementing the listeners and having the common implementations implemented, leave the rest without implementation so the others activities have to override it:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnSocketListener {
    public void commonMethod() {
        //Some Implementation that it's common to all
    }
}
```

4 - Have your others activities inherit from that base activity:

```
public class SomeActivity extends BaseActivity {
    //implements all the others methods
}
```

if you want to to share the same socket you can make it a singleton:

```
public class SocketClass {
        private OnSockectListener mListener;
        private static SockectClass mInstance;

        private SocketClass() {
        }

        public SockectClass getInstance() {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new SockectClass();
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        public void setListener(OnSockectListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

       private void someEvent() {
           if (mListener != nul) {
               mListener.onSomeEvent(Data data);
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it works pretty well. However how can I manage the issue about having a common socket for multiple activities because the listener is set only from an activity, not all of them ?

For example I have a socket returning profile informations, could be nice to manipulate the data and views trough multiple activities.

Comment: Why don't have socket to be a singleton?

Comment: Good idea, will have a look on it.

Comment: I'm still testing the best way... still locked in my architecture to manage the multiple sockets. but yep it looks like working in the basics... Will marked it as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You cold create a [BoundService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and put the socket there. Your activities will bind to the service and call the methods.

Or you could communicate with your Socket.class using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).